# Perl - undefind variable - why?

Tags: perl, hashmap

Why does the following gives the following output? $a1 is defined...

```
package A1;
use Hash::Merge;
use Data::Dumper;
  
sub new 
{
    my $class = shift;
    my $self =
    {
        length => 2,
    };
    return bless $self, $class;
}

1;


my $a1 = A1->new();
print("a1 = " . ref($a1) . "\n");

my %a = {'1' => $a1};

my $a3 = \%a;
print( Dumper($a3));
```

output:

```
a1 = A1
$VAR1 = {
          'HASH(0x247c568)' => undef
        };
```

I would've expected for the value to be a 'A1(0x...)' and not just undefined...

Comment: If you had used `use warnings` you would not be asking this question. Never write Perl code without `use strict; use warnings`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The curly braces introduce a hash reference, but `%a` is a hash, not a reference. Therefore, the reference was stringified and used as the key, and there was nothing to use as the value, so it remained undefined.

Try

```perl
my %a = (1 => $a1);
```

instead.

You can also create the reference directly without `%a`:

```perl
my $a3 = {'1' => $a1};
```

You should always `use warnings;`. Perl would've told you

> Reference found where even-sized list expected at ...